# Recovering iWork from backup

Tags: time-machine, iwork, recovery

I recently changed my MBP 13" 2009 to the newer MBP 13" 2012.
I decided not to recover from Time Machine and install everything manually as to make a clean start.

> Although I do not have my iWork '09 disk with me. Is there a way to
>   recover it from the backups? Simply copying the application does not
>   work.

Also I am not able to download it from App Store, because I bought it from a retail store and not online.

Comment: I had some problems with iWork, so I ended up with installing OpenOffice for Mac.

Comment: I havent tried OpenOffice so cant compare them. Im quite happy with iWork though, it havent had any problems with it so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to recover library files:

```
/Library/Application Support/iWork'09
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork09.installer.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork09.plist
```

In my case, this was the minimum requirement to get Keynote starting again.

Additionally, you might want to recover user-specific files from your user directory:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iWork
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork.*
```

Comment: Marked as accepted answer even tho I havent tried your suggestions. I got access to the install DVDs which solved the issue.

Comment: I can confirm that guwac's approach works.